# Mini ultra light linux boot on a USB key

Tags: linux, distribution-choice, live-usb, bootable

I don't have linux. I'm on Windows (XP or 7).

I'd like to have just a linux USB key only to boot and have the command line to launch some command line programs. How may I simply create that USB key (256 Mb available) ? Do you know some Windows tools that would allow me to do that without having to make all by hand each time ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Tiny Core Linux](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/downloads.html); it takes 8mb

Comment: Additionally, Tiny Core Linux makes it easy to tailor your own distribution, say to work well with your Windows installation.

Answer (score 1):

In 256 Mb you can have GUI, web browser, text editor and a music player! Install [puppy linux](http://puppylinux.org/) on your usb. It is a fully operational Linux with a nice UI (and terminal to run commands). You can find instructions at [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/puppy-linux-on-usb/).
If you want something even smaller then have a look at [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/).

**Edit**: You can set init to 3 from 5 in file `/etc/inittab` after installation.

Comment: I don't want any UI, just the command line at boot.

Comment: updated answer based on the comment.